# Animate UIView swap with layout constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am swapping one UIView for another—removing one and adding the other, which works fine. I would like to animate the transition, which should be easy, but the problem is that I need to add layout constraints on the view I'm adding. (The constraints on the added view are different from those on the one I'm removing.)

I'm not trying to animate the change in constraints. They need to be in place so the view is shown at the correct size, and the correct size varies depending on the screen size.

Setting up the new constraints in the animation block obviously crashes because the view hierarchy isn't yet set up. Setting them in the completion block is too late—they get added, but the new view comes in wrong and doesn't lay out correctly with the new constraints until the next time I update the view, which causes the layout to "jump" from wrong to right.

```
UIView.transition(with: containerView,
                  duration: 0.3,
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                  animations: {
                    self.containerView.addSubview(targetView)
                    self.currentView.removeFromSuperview()
                  }, completion: { _ in
                    self.currentView = targetView
                    self.setupConstraints()
                  })
```

Is there a way to work around this? I feel like I'm missing something but I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: You can just hide the view and set it constraint, on the last line then show it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup all the views and constraints at beginning (e.g set alpha = 0 for targetView), then just animation view's alpha and constraints, remove unnecessary views when all animations finish.

Comment: Works perfectly. Imagine me smacking myself in the head for not thinking of it! Thanks.